# Clobber existing file with ar

Tags: bash, unix, unix-ar

When using `ar` with an archive name that already exists, this message is generated:

```
+ ar rcs /tmp/libcpfs.a.3nbsv /tmp/cpfs.c.ERGsn /tmp/log.c.1lk6G
ar: /tmp/libcpfs.a.3nbsv: File format not recognized
```

The existing archive name is either an empty file (created by `mktemp`).

I want to clobber whatever contents are there anyway, the contents of any existing file (be it an `ar` or not) don't interest me. How can I enforce this?

### Update0

I'm currently using `rm "$libcpfs_a" && ar rcs "${libcpfs_a}" ${libcpfs_objs[*]}` as a workaround.

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, you'll get an error message and `ar` won't be executed. Use `rm -f` and a semicolon (instead of `&&`).

Comment: @Dennis: Yes good point, thanks. Fortunately I'm `mktemp`'ing the empty file on the preceding line, but good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forcibly removing the file before calling `ar`.

```
rm -f $file
ar rcs $file foo.c bar.c
```